# iOS autolayout vs ScrollView : Contentsize issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

**What I Need**

I have a scrollView with the following hierarchy :

> ScrollView
>   . ^ contentView(UIView)
>   . - ^ view1(yellow)
>   . - ^ view2(gray)

[image]

`view1`(Yellow) has a fixed height and is pinned to the top of the contentView. I have specified all the constraints except for the height `view2`. coz I am adding a subview to `view2`(gray) programmatically and will be of random height.

The problem is that I am at a loss on how to set the height constraint of `view2`. scrollview needs to have constraints running from top through bottom in order to calculate the `contentSize`. But the height of `view2` will only be fixed after the subview is added, which will have all the necessary constraints for determining the height, of course.

**What I  tried**

**1)** My first plan was to add the subview and set its constraints programmatically to make the scrollview happy. like so :

```
detailsView = [ProfileDetailsView instantiateFromNib];
[self.detailHolder addSubview:detailsView];

[self.detailHolder addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:detailsView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.detailHolder
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];

[self.detailHolder addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:detailsView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.detailHolder
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];

[self.detailHolder addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:detailsView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.detailHolder
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];

[self.detailHolder addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:detailsView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.detailHolder
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
```

The problem is that xcode gives me an error that `ScrollView has ambiguous scrollable content height`. I cannot give a fixed height for `view2` because the subview that I am later adding will have all the necessary constraints to set the `ScrollView`'s `contentSize.

**2)** Then I tried adding a height constraint to `view2` with a lower priority so that when the subviews constraints kick in, the height constraint would get overriden. but that doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give view2 a placeholder size which would be removed at runtime automatically to make auto layout system happy

[image]

Comment: Wow! worked like a charm!! thanks buddy. and one thing - it didnt work at first, but then I added `detailsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` and it worked. I will add that and accept. thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I forgot,  auto layout systen would automatically translate view's autoresizing mask to constraints, so you should set it to no manually

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, 
you to add height constraint to the view2 and link an IBOutlet to the height constraint.

As

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
```

Then, just before you programmatically add constraints for subview of view2, remove the height constraint from view2, using

```
 [view2 removeConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
```

and then add your constraints programmatically.